# How to use Web Browser's BACK-BUTTON ? in java web applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications, browser, back-button

in javascript we can call    history.back( ); method to go back to previous page. is there any way to implement same functionality in java web applications / servlets?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Procedure:

- You can use a session object conatining a Stack where each item of
  the Stack contains URI of a visited page.
- On each request in your Servlet you have to push the request URI to
  the stack.
- When you want do do "Back", you just pop the Stack and you redirect
  to the URI you got from the top of the Stack.